# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Xorg high CPU usage while Sound Settings opened

Tags: sound, 20.04, xorg, cpu-load

Several days ago I found huge lags over all system on my Ubuntu. Today I think found the problem, but not the reason. So when I open Settings -> Sound menu, the CPU usage comes to about 100%. If I close Settings window or go to other tab, it becomes OK. Nothing special in my sound configuration - monitor and notebook with built in audio and Bluetooth headset. Same worked just fine on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

So does anyone have same problems with Sound menu? What the reason of it and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this is also the case in my 20.04 system. Opening the Sound settings window, makes Xorg use 100% CPU and starts lagging the entire system. The only solution is to log out and back in again, or restart the machine. Following this question in case someone posts a solution.

Comment: I can report a similar issue. In my system Xorg does not use 100% CPU but it draws enough resources to spike up fan speed and noise. The only way to end it is to terminate the session.